# ob-async issue, seq-random-elt not defined

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, async

I would like to asynchronously run code blocks in org mode.

My org mode version (`org-version` output) is: `Org mode version 9.2.1 (9.2.1-23-g126a37-elpa @ /home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/org-9.2.2/)`

I followed some instructions on this blog: http://cachestocaches.com/2018/6/org-literate-programming/

I installed `ob-async`.

I have a very simple Python code block in my org mode file:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :async
import random
random.seed(1)
print("Hello World! Here's a random number: {}".format(random.random()))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: f6d3fcf77d5cbec033f91b7dc23ebfe5
```

The result looks weird and every time I try to run the code block I see a messages in the messages buffer:

```
executing Python code block...
error in process sentinel: async-handle-result: Symbol’s value as variable is void: seq-random-elt
error in process sentinel: Symbol’s value as variable is void: seq-random-elt
```

I could not find anything helpful about this error so far.

How can I get asynchronous code execution from org source blocks to work properly?

## Edit

I tried the following using `emacs -Q` startup:

In my `*scratch*` buffer I have the following content:

```
;; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; To create a file, visit it with C-x C-f and enter text in its buffer.

(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(require 'ob-async)

(setq org-babel-load-languages
      (quote
       ((emacs-lisp . t)
    (python . t)
    (scheme . t)
    (sh . t))))
```

Then I press `C-j` to evaluate.
Then I open my `.org` file, which has the following source block and run the source block:

```
* Async Code Exec

Async package has issues and does not work?

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :async
import random
import time

random.seed(1)
time.sleep(5)
print("Hello World! Here's a random number: {}".format(random.random()))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Hello World! Here's a random number: 0.13436424411240122
```

The result is, that the `time.sleep(5)` blocks emacs and is not run asynchronously. However, at least the result is fine, even if that was not the main reason for creating this question.

The same blocking behavior happens when I try it with an elisp source block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output :async
(progn (sleep-for 5) (print 1))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: 1
```

## Edit 2

- My Emacs version is: `GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.21)`.

## Edit 3

Running the following code also results in `seq-random-elt` being void error:

```
(async-start
   ;; What to do in the child process
   (lambda ()
     (message "This is a test")
     (sleep-for 3)
     222)

   ;; What to do when it finishes
   (lambda (result)
     (message "Async process done, result should be 222: %s" result)))
```

The error:

```
executing Elisp code block...
error in process sentinel: async-handle-result: Symbol’s value as variable is void: seq-random-elt
error in process sentinel: Symbol’s value as variable is void: seq-random-elt
```

## Edit 4

Here is the issue on Github, which I created for the problem: https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async/issues/55

## Edit 5

Sorry for asking this obviously bad question ...

Comment: I don't see the error. Have you tried with emacs -Q, and does it work with emacs-lisp? For example: `(progn (sleep-for 1) (print 1)`? You could also try requiring the seq library.

Comment: @jagrg With `emacs -Q` I have no setup for Python, so I tried your elisp. The result was, that it did not run asynchronously. I guess that is, because `ob-async` does not load when I run emacs like that and the `:async` is ignored. I also cannot eval `(require 'ob-async)` then, because "Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, ob-async". However, when I start emacs with my configuration (where I do require `ob-async`) it does not show any error about not being able to find it.

Comment: With emacs -Q switch to the scratch buffer and add only the configuration you need. For example, you might need `(require 'package)`, `(package-initialize)` and `(require 'ob-async)` in addition to your `org-babel-load-languages` settings. Then eval the buffer and try the example above. If it works then you will have to bisect your init file to find out what part of your configuration is causing the problem. If it still fails I would suggest re-installing Org with the instructions [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html).

Comment: @jagrg I will add results of those tests to the original post. TLDR: When doing that  with `emacs -Q` the `:async` is ignored, but at least the output is no longer strange.

Comment: Are you able to run the example [here](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async) under async-start?

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using? `seq-random-elt` was introduced in 26.x by the looks of it.

Comment: @phils Ah, if that is true, it is apparently the issue: `GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.21)` I will add it to the question.

Comment: @Zelphir Please raise a bug report for `ob-async` -- it should state its minimum Emacs version requirement correctly.

Comment: @jagrg I added that code run as well in the original post. See edit 3.

Comment: @phils OK, it is created and I will add it to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is essentially that `ob-async` has a bug (either with how it implements this feature, or with its stated minimum supported verion of Emacs).

- The user is running Emacs 25.2.2
- `seq-random-elt` was introduced in Emacs 26
- `ob-async` states `emacs-24.4` as its minimum requirement

Most likely this will be resolved upstream in https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async/issues/55